# Monic Generator and Ideals of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

> Is the set of all polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ s.t. $P(1)=P(3)=0$ an ideal? If so find the monic generator.

I do not think it is because if we have $P(x)=x^2$, then $x*x^2=x^3$ which means $P(3)$ is not $0$, am i right?

I also do not know what monic generator is and have a hard time finding a good explanation so I was wondering if one could offer a simple explanation on what monic generator is and give an example on it, e.g. all polynomials of degree $\ge n$ (since i think that is ideal.)

Comment: Is the question whether the set $\{P \in Q[X] : P(1) = P(3) = 0\}$ is an ideal of $Q[X]$? Also, what is $Q$?

Comment: It is both if it is an ideal and if so find the generator (I do not thin kit is ideal so no generator) and Q is rationals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a subset $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is an *ideal* if and only if for all $r \in R$ and $x, y \in I$, we have $rx \in I$ and $x + y \in I$. So, in your example, $R = \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $I = \{P \in \mathbb{Q}[x] : P(1) = P(3) = 0\}$, and you have to determine whether, for all polynomials $P \in I$ and all polynomials $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (note: $f$ may or may not be in $I$, it's an arbitrary polynomial), the polynomial $f \cdot P$ is also in $I$.

Your example with $x^2$ and $x$ is not a counterexample, because neither of these polynomials evaluate to zero at $x = 1$ or $x = 3$. (Of course, that doesn't mean by itself that the set *isn't* an ideal, just that you haven't proven it is or it isn't yet.) Also, the set of all polynomials of degree at least $n$ is not an ideal, because the sum of two polynomials of degree $n$ can have degree less than $n$, so the set isn't closed under addition.

About "monic generators": This relies on a theorem that states that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a *principal ideal domain*, meaning that every ideal is a *principal ideal*, that is, an ideal of the form $(g) = \{f \cdot g : f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\}$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. In fact, this is still true if $\mathbb{Q}$ is replaced with any field. The key idea of the proof is the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials, which lets us show that, if an ideal contains two polynomials, then it also contains their GCD.

It's an easy exercise to prove that, for any nonzero $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, we have $(g) = (cg)$. So, by choosing $c$ to be the reciprocal of the leading coefficient of $g$, we see that each ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has a generator that's a monic polynomial. Also, this is unique, since if there were two distinct such monic generators, we could take their GCD and find a new generator of smaller degree, which is a contradiction. (For example: the unique monic generator of the ideal $(2x^3 + 4)$ is $x^3 + 2$.)

So, if $I = \{P \in \mathbb{Q}[x] : P(1) = P(3) = 0\}$ is an ideal, the second part of the problem is asking you to find the unique monic polynomial $g \in I$ such that $I = (g)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider the map $\mathbb Q[x] \to \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ given by $P \mapsto (P(1),P(3))$. Prove that this map is a ring homomorphism whose kernel is the given set.